# How to change the default black address bar in Chrome 74

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, address-bar

It looks so horrible, the black address bar and the new dark theme. I really want to get the old one back, not because I'm resistant to changes I just really don't like it it's too much contrast and is always in the peripheral view compared to the white pages. I tried changing to the pro-grey theme and it worked fine, but after the update it seems like they don't allow to change the black address bar!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Open your Terminal
2. Enter next command: ​defaults write com.google.Chrome NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool YES
3. Relaunch Chrome app
4. You are beautiful...

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/b0ijel/how_do_you_disable_chromes_dark_mode/?st=jtr1pfqy&sh=e691bef2 via https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2707959?msgid=3099491